# Java error Default constructor cannot handle exception type SQLException thrown by implicit super constructor. Must define an explicit constructor

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

I am trying to get jdbc connection in spring boot but I'm getting java error

> "Default constructor cannot handle exception type SQLException thrown
>   by implicit super constructor. Must define an explicit constructor."

Here is the connection object that is getting the error.

```
Connection con = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();
```

Below is the code where I'm trying to use con object.

```
private String queryBuilder(DetailsRequest request, Map<String, String> headers) throws SQLException {

    StringBuilder AcctNameBuilder= new StringBuilder();
final String QUERY = "select * " +  "from gfc.LSI_ELGBLTY " + "where INSURANCE_ID = ? and " + "SYS_CD = ? and " + "ACCT_TYPE in (?)";
                prSt = con.prepareStatement(QUERY);
                prSt.setString(1, request.getInsuranceId());
                prSt.setString(2, request.getSystemId());
                prSt.setString(3, AcctNameBuilder.toString());
                rs = prSt.executeQuery();
                System.out.println(rs);
}
```

Comment: Can you show the full method?

Comment: (One should close con, prSt and rs.)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the original implementation of getConnection:

```
Connection getConnection() throws SQLException;
```

This means `getConnection` may throw  `SQLException`, and in that constructor you are trying to get connection while not properly handling the exception.

As a **quick/dirty** workaround you can:

- wrapping it in a try catch statement
- or just make the constructor throws **SQLException**.

> **Please also note that handling exception in constructor *is not a good practice* and as a result not recommended, and you find a
>   approach it in a more proper way.**